# How to change editor used by php artisan tinker

Tags: php, laravel, vim, tinker

When you type `edit` in laravel's tinker shell, it pops up a nano editor for you to type your commands in. The thing is I'm more comfortable with vim and I'm wondering if there's a way to change the default editor from nano to vim.

I already tried `export EDITOR=vim` in my `.bashrc` (and `.zshrc` just incase), to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to modify your `.bash_profile` to contain `export EDITOR=vim`. It seems tinker uses that file rather than your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Comment: Your shell doesn't source those files randomly so you shouldn't try them randomly. Unless you have a very weird setup, `.zshrc` is only relevant if your shell is zsh and whether bash sources `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` is a matter of how it is started: `$ man bash` and then `/INVOCATION`.

Answer (score 0):

I only append `export EDITOR=vim` in my `.zshrc` and it works!

I think you forgot to run `source ~/.zshrc` after the changes.